# Open specific explorer path with admin application and prevent UAC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, process, admin, uac, rights

I have an annoying issue and really need help on this, because I am running out of ideas.

Actual state:
I have an application that will be opened in administrative mode, means: I open the application as admin. Working environment is within a domain. My admin user is inside the Administrator Group.
From within the application, I start some more processes. Furthermore, I open a specific share within the network (which requires an Admin account to be accessible). My admin accout has all required rights.

Issue:
When opening the share, UAC pops up all the time needing me to enter my credentials. Why is this the case? I mean, I open the share from an application, which is started from an admin user who has all neccessary rights.

Desired state:
I want to prevent UAC from popping up when trying to access the network share.

Hope you'll get my point here.

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks in advance, 
Jens

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are hitting the issue of the user being stripped of admin privelages on the **remote** server.

The remote server itself is **also** running with UAC enabled. That means that when the user **Jens** tries to connect to a server, the server also counts you as a *standard* user until you elevate.

This option is described, and enabled in the group policy setting `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`:

> To better protect those users who are members of the local Administrators group, we implement UAC restrictions on the network. This mechanism helps prevent against "loopback" attacks. This mechanism also helps prevent local malicious software from running remotely with administrative rights.
>
> When a user who is a member of the local administrators group on the target remote computer establishes a remote administrative connection by using the net use * \remotecomputer\Share$ command, for example, they will not connect as a full administrator. The user has no elevation potential on the remote computer, and the user cannot perform administrative tasks. If the user wants to administer the workstation with a Security Account Manager (SAM) account, the user must interactively log on to the computer that is to be administered with Remote Assistance or Remote Desktop, if these services are available.

This group policy option is disabled on Domain joined machines.

See [KB951016 - Description of User Account Control and remote restrictions in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016)

for how to disable it.

The issue is that the remote server authenticates you independently of what your local machine thinks of you. That means that if you were an administrator, but running as standard user, you could simply talk to a network server with full admin rights.